# Most Efficient way to get the <title> of a URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It's simple to do a webrequest, get the page and parse the html to get the title of the page.

But I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way that is faster, and doesn't require downloading the whole html?

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways is to write a custom parser which **immediately** aborts parsing and closes the connection when the `</title>` has been passed in the stream. You'll only need to ensure that the code doesn't buffer the entire stream in memory beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the author has added some kind of x-title header, you will have to stream the html to at least the title tag.